# Yii framework for building API's

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have been working with Yii for some years, since version 1. I think is an awesome framework.

Today I need to build a website using Yii which includes building an API, administrator and frontend site.

In the past when I have worked in other similar projects. I shared model between them, each side (api, frontend and administrator) have their own controllers.

With Yii I am trying to find a way to organize it to take advantage of the full power of yii.

I was planning to use API only for mobile apps not for web frontend to be able to use Yii validation rules, etc and speed up the project.

Project owner wants to build a frontend which reads data through API too, that will bring duplicated validation rules etc.

If I follow project owner requirement it will be like managing 3 projects
1. Api + Backend
2. Frontend
3. Mobile

If I follow the other option, it will be like managing 2 projects:
1. API + Frontend + Backend
2. Mobile

Any advice?

Comment: Use advanced template (backend, common, frontent), and just copypaste `frontend` to `rest` for API application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the advanced application template, make the common directory a git subtree. Then, you can use the subtree in any number of projects. There you are maintaining only one set of models for several applications. Works great for me.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes I usually do that. My problem now is if I set communication from / to the frontend using the API, I will not be able to use same model rules, have you found a way to do it?